# Dont know where to fix perl basic

Tags: perl

This is the Question

Write a Perl program to accomplish each of the following on the file solar.txt (see link at the class homepage)

1. Print all records that do not list a discoverer in the eighth field.
2. Print every record after erasing the second field. Note: It would be better to say "print every record" omitting the second field.
3. Print the records for satellites that have negative orbital periods. (A negative orbital period simply means that the satellite orbits in a counterclockwise direction.)
4. Print the data for the objects discovered by the Voyager2 space probe.
5. Print each record with the orbital period given in seconds rather than days.

About solar.txt file:

This file contains lines of 9 items, the first being:

```
Adrastea XV Jupiter 129000 0.30 0.00 0.00 Jewitt 1979
```

in alphabetical order by the name of the planet or moon (first field).

The text in [] is the corresponding field from the line above.

The fields in this file are:

1. Name of planet or moon [Adrastea]
2. Number of moon or planet (roman numerals) [XV]
3. Name of the abject around which the satellite orbits [Jupiter]
4. Orbital radius (semimajor axis) in kilometers [129000]
5. Orbital period in days [0.30]
6. Orbital inclination in degrees [0.00]
7. Orbital eccentricity [0.00]
8. Discoverer [Jewitt]
9. Year of discovery [1979]

my code is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;

open(FILE, "<solar.txt") or die "Can't open file, $!";

while(<FILE>) {
    my $tmp = split(/ /, $file);
    if($tmp[7] eq '-') {
        print "@tmp";
    }
}

while(<FILE>) {
    splice(/ /, 1, 1);
    print "FILE\n";
}

while(<FILE>) {
    my @tmp = split(/ /, FILE);
    if($tmp[4] < 0) {
        print "@tmp\n";
    }
}

while(<FILE>) {
    my @tmp = split(/ /, FILE);
    if($tmp[7] eq 'Voyager2') {
        print "@tmp\n";
    }
}

while(<FILE>) {
    my @tmp = split(/ /, FILE);
    @tmp = $tmp[4] * 24 * 60 * 60;
    print "$tmp\n";
}

close(FILE);
```

when I try to run it, it says use of uninitialized value error.
But I don't know where to fix. please help me.

Comment: you need `use strict;` at the top of your file

Comment: I tried that one but new error comes up, says Bareword "FILE" not allowed while "strict subs" in use......

Comment: I'm using DWIM Perl 5.14.2.1 (v7) this one.

Comment: Your first `while (<FILE>)` loop read the entire file. The second loop reads nothing, because the entire file has already been read.

Comment: so do I need to remove while(<FILE>) after first one?

Comment: Please don't change the code in your question when people point out the cause of your issues. That will make things confusing for future visitors who come to this page; they will see a question that says "I'm doing Y, why isn't it working?" followed by answers that say "You're doing X, you should do Y."

Comment: Changing your question also invalidates any answers that have already been submitted. Please post questions/concerns in the form of a comment or ask a new question to address any other problems you are having.

Answer (score 1):

You say:

```
open(FILE, "<solar.txt") or die "Can't open file, $!";
```

then:

```
my $tmp = split(/ /, $file);
```

What do you expect to be in the previously-undeclared, uninitialized `$file`?

And later:

```
my @tmp = split(/ /, FILE);
```

Here you're trying to `split` a file handle. That's not going to do what you want.

In both cases, you really want `$_` (the line read in the most-recent `<FILE>` call).

So:

```
my @tmp = split(/ /, $_);
```

But since ([q.v.](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)):

> If only PATTERN is given, EXPR defaults to `$_` .

You can just say:

```
my @tmp = split(/ /);
```

Comment: Thanks, after I fix it my result gets a little better, but still there's error and says use of uninitialized value $tmp[7] in string eq . Can you help me this one??

Comment: Without seeing the input data? Not really. Are you sure you have 8 items in that array? (`[0..7]`)

Comment: The line `my $tmp = split(/ /);` should be `my @tmp = split(/ /);`

Comment: And that last `print "$tmp\n";` should probably be  `print "@tmp\n";`

Comment: And Keith T. is right about the first `while()` loop eating up the whole file. None of the other `while()` loops will ever read anything.